# In NodeJS, how do I test for an event emitted by a class method that parses a POST API request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

Basically, I'm testing a StreamReader that emits events when a POST request executes causing the stream reader to parse and emit a `data` event.

I'm using `mocha`, `chai` (with `chai-http`), and `sinon.spy` to test a specific scenario in which a class that calls a REST API receives a response and then emits a "data" event in the response handler to other event listeners.

I've read a lot about using `chai-http` with Promises to test the response with assert and expect. To that end, I am attempting to use the same pattern to test for a data event, but even with Promises, the `sinon.spy` listener is not triggered until after the Promise is fulfilled and test case is complete.

On to the test cases...

**FIRST ATTEMPT - Using `sinon.spy` as a callback**

```
it('should emit a "data" event when one record is POSTed and parsed', function() {
  let spy = sinon.spy();
  let reader = new Reader(sync_query);
  reader.on('data', spy);
  return chai.request(SYNC_URI)
    .post('/db/_bulk_docs')
    .set("Content-type", "application/json")
    .send({ "docs": [{"user": "tempura"}, {"user": "shrimp"}] })
    .then(function(response){
      expect(response.body).to.have.lengthOf(2);
      sinon.assert.calledOnce(spy);  
      // Executes too soon. I can see the event in another listener's logs. 
      // I'd like the test to run until the spy fires or a timeout occurs.
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      throw error;
    });
    // EXITS BEFORE EVENTS are triggered?
});
```

**EDIT 1 - Using a standard callback**

```
it('should emit a "data" event when one record is POSTed and parsed', function() {
  let reader = new CouchReader(sync_query);
  // This works perfectly to catch when the event is fired but...
  reader.on('data', function(evt) {
    try {
      assert.isOk(evt);
      done();
    } catch (error) {
      done(error);
    }
  });
  chai.request(SYNC_GATEWAY_URI)
    .post('/db/_bulk_docs')
    .set("Content-type", "application/json")
    .send({ "docs": [{"user": "toszter"}, {"user": "bartacus"}] })
    .then(function(response){
      // ...the next expect doesn't get caught when thrown.
      // Can't return chai.request as a promise b/c of the callback.
      expect(response.body).to.have.lengthOf(3);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      throw error;
    });
  this.timeout(4000);
});
```

I wonder if...

1. I should transform the code below into a deferred promise and return the whole block to mocha since the assertions in `chai.request` are orthogonal to the assertion in the callback, but both affect the outcome of the test, OR ...
2. I should split this into two separate tests that test the units individually... one for the call back event emit, and the other for the response to the `/db/_bulk_docs` request?

Your vote probably is with Option 2, yes?

I've tried using a non-Promise version by passing in `done` (correctly?), then `setImmediate()` and now considering `process.nextTick()` but first, I as others with more experience using mocha (etc.) to test similar scenarios:

1. How do we prevent the test case from finishing until an event is either caught by the listener or timeout after 30s of silence?
2. Should I be using a vanilla NodeJS `request` module instead?

Pardon me if there's a duplicate out there, but in my searches, I couldn't find one...

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best answer to this, but I have arrived at a solution. My OP is a question of integration testing, much more than a unit. I'm attempting to test (these units):

1. The API Request to the DB Gateway Server works and responds with the inputs.
2. The DB Gateway Server activity is "detected" by the Reader Class API montiors.
3. The `data` event is emitted by the Reader Class.
4. The `data` event is packaged with the inputs I sent to the API Request.

That's a *too much* to put on one test case and a valuable lesson.

**Instead, I test each case independently, using only the code that each needs.**

```
describe.only('#message', function() {
  it('should emit a "bdata" event when message is called.', function() {
    let spy = sinon.spy();
    let reader = new Reader(sync_query);
    reader.on('data', spy);
    reader.message({obj: {last_seq: 1}});
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(spy); // Hooray, it works!
  });
});
```

But if I'm really after an end-to-end integration test in one fell swoop of a sharp axe, then *why not?* as they say in Pushkar.

```
describe('#message event', function() {
  it('should emit a "data" event when Server saves data via Gateway APIs', function(done) {
    let reader = new CouchReader(sync_query);
    reader.on('data', function(evt) { // <-- I could make this a spy()
      try {
        assert.isOk(evt);
        // assert the event payload here
        done();
      } catch (error) {
        done(error);
      }
    });
    chai.request(SYNC_GATEWAY_URI)
      .post('/db/_bulk_docs')
      .set("Content-type", "application/json")
      .send({ "docs": [{"user": "toszter"}, {"user": "bartacus"}] })
      .catch(function(error) {
        throw error;
      });
    this.timeout(4000);
  });
});
```

...and in this case if it times out, then I've lost my paddle and a new quest begins.